# How can i skip extra rows in excel while importing it into database using SqlBulkCopy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am importing ExcelSheet into SQL server database, the problem I have is that the ExcelSheet has around 25 columns while the database table has 15 rows. I need to skip the extra unwanted rows in excel, e.g:

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
{                  
   bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("PP NO", "passportnumber");
   bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("COVER NO", "covernumber");
   bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NAME", "paxname");
   .....
}
```

The error I am getting is 
`The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination.`

Comment: which add() is the error pointing to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this and let me know the status

```
OdbcConnection connection;
SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy;
string ConnectionString = @"server=hostname\sqlexpress;database=pubs;uid=sa;pwd=1234;";
string connstr = @"Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;Dbq=c:\contact.xls";
using (connection = new OdbcConnection(connstr))
{

OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);

//you can change [Sheet1$] with your sheet name
connection.Open();

// Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet

using (OdbcDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())

{

// Bulk Copy to SQL Server



using (bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConnectionString))
{

 // I have given column name "id" in the excel and "empId" sql table, 

 bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("id","empId");
 bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("name","name");

    OR
// You can give index directly
 bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(0,0);
 bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(1,1);

bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Names";
//"Names" is the sql table where you want to copy all data
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
}
dr.Close();
}
}

bulkCopy.Close();
```

Comment: @Arbaaz: Only thing is column names in the excel file and column names in the destination table should match.

Comment: What if i have column name id in excel but empid in sqltable?

Comment: you havent mapped column , the names of column in excel and database are different and also there are extra columns in excel

Comment: @Arbaaz: Column mapping are case-sensitive. So Source column should ( same spelling) match with given datasource. And also destination column should match with sql table. OR else you can use the column index for the source and destination. Please refer my post

Comment: @Arbaaz: Please refer this link for more information http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/04/sqlbulkcopy-columnmappings-mismatch.html

Comment: The problem was that :
though i tried bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("id","empId");
but while reading excel sheet i was using select empid from Sheet1 (empid did not exist, i chaged it to id and it worked)

Answer (score 1):

ColumnMappings are case-sensitive. The Source Column name and Destination Column name spelling are not the same, you have to check and write the same column names in Tables as well.